# Necessary and sufficient condition for a function to be contraction

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, functional-equations, nonlinear-optimization

In my book there is a theorem which says that-

>
 Let a function $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable function. Then $f$ is contraction iff $\exists \alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(x)|≤\alpha$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$.

My question: I can prove the same question for any interval $I$, irrespective of closed interval, though one part is obvious, any if $f$ is contraction then $|f'(x)|≤\alpha \forall x \in I$

For converse part I use Lagrange's mean value theorem
Let us take any $x,y \in I$ then applying mean value theorem on $[x,y]$ $\exists c\in (x,y)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|≤f'(c)|x-y|$
From hypothesis $f'(c)≤\alpha$, where $\alpha\in (0,1)$
Therefore we have $|f(x)-f(y)|≤\alpha|x-y|$, $\alpha\in (0,1)$
$\Rightarrow$ $f$ is contraction on $I$.

Can anybody tell me that I did something wrong in proof or my my proof is not wrong and proposition claimed by me is true.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). (to help you get started, I have edited the post a bit.)

Comment: If the main point of you post is that you want to check whether the proof is correct (as opposed to asking for any proof of this claim), you should probably mark the question using the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag.

Comment: @martin slezing yess I realise my faults...

Comment: Actually I am learning math Jax....thanks for editing